# Reading the server time instead of the users time

Tags: php, date

I'm using this function to get the date of the last Saturday (The Saturday of this week):

```
$saturday = strtotime("last Saturday");
```

The function outputs the date correctly, however when I change the date of my PC, the output returns according to the new date, so is there a way I can force PHP to read the date of the server not the date of the user's PC?

Comment: `strtotime` does indeed read the date of the server. Are you sure you're not working in a dev environment, i.e. your PC _is_ a server?

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly (I'm sleepy ATM), but when you run that script on a server, it will take that date won't it, therefore you don't need to change anything?

Answer (score 6):

It uses the server date. My guess is that you host your PHP server on the same PC, and this is why you are getting this result.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no access to the users time. So when you change your time, and the time changes in the browser I think you are hosting the server on localhost.

if you want to check that it takes the servers time, change the server where you host the page

Answer (score 0):

use

```
time()
```

if you want it formated use

```
$now = time();
$formated = date("format", $now);
//for format google php date function
```